# exception while sending mail

Tags: asp.net

I am sending mail but it is giving me exception

```
Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, relaying denied from your location [182.72.17.210] (#5.7.1)
```

my code

```
 public static string SendMailHtmlFromat(string sForm, string sTo, string sSub, string sMsg)
        {
            MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage();
            mailmsg.To.Add(sTo);
            mailmsg.From = new MailAddress(sForm);
            mailmsg.Subject = sSub;
            mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailmsg.Body = sMsg;
            try
            {
                //SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net", 25);
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@beautiful.com", "Smart123");
                smtp.Send(mailmsg);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {     }
            return "";
        }
```

is their any problem in SmtpClient declaring

Comment: Contact your ISP (relay-hosting.secureserver.net). At first glance, relaying appears to be denied from your location...

Comment: Michael is spot on. Additionally, if your ISP is using IIS for SMTP (JUST IN CASE :-)) this is how you can configure relaying permissions http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/peter.van.ooijen/Relay_5F00_4A28FAA2.png

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link.
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10227041/exception-while-sending-mail.aspx